# Open url with variable syntax

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a variable `agencyWebsite` and a label that should open the website when clicked with this method:

```
- (void)website1LblTapped {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.agencyWebsite];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

I get a warning in the compiler saying:

```
Incompatible pointer types sending UILabel* to parameter of type NSString*
```

And the app crashes when the link is clicked. Any suggestions?

Edit: Here is what I am doing to make the label clickable

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* website1LblGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(website1LblTapped)];
    // if labelView is not set userInteractionEnabled, you must do so
    [self.agencyWebsite setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.agencyWebsite addGestureRecognizer:website1LblGesture];
```

What i used to get it working

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", self.agencyWebsite.text]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `agencyWebsite` is of type `UILabel*`, you need to access its `text` property instead of passing the object itself to `URLWithString:`.

```
- (void)website1LblTapped {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.agencyWebsite.text];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Calling `self.agencyWebsite` will return your `UILabel*` object, whereas `self.agencyWebsite.text` will return a `NSString*` object containing the text from the label.

Comment: ok that makes a lot of sense, I have made the changes and have no more errors or crashes but nothing happens now when I click on the label :(

Comment: Well, it looks like a different question now :) Sorry, but you have to give more details. I believe it's best to open a new question as you seem to have solved your initial problem.

Comment: @Paul.s No it does not where would I add that?

Comment: Well, *self.agencyWebsite.text* returns the text of the label, i.e. the exact text you can read on your screen. Set *self.agencyWebsite.text* when you create it !

Comment: In front of the url e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com`. You might be best to some how clarify to the user that they either need to add it or that you will add it.